# Is "dress" a liable verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, transitivity

Can we use the verb "**dress**" without a direct object or should we only use the phrasal-verb "**dress up**"? How different are these two sentences?

- I dressed and came out.
- I dressed up and came out.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you about the transitivity of "dress" and why didn't it help?

Comment: I didn't look in the dictionary.

Comment: "dress up" means to wear something fancy or dress in something fancy. It can also mean to improve the appearance of something: "dress up windows with drapes" or "dress up a speech with fancy words or quotations from famous people." The verb "dress" by itself can mean a lot more things than just "putting clothes on", so you should take a look at it.

Comment: Might I ask what a "liable verb" is? I have never heard "liable" used this way and I've looked it up to see whether it is a grammatical term and I cannot find anything on it.

Comment: The salient interpretation of intransitive "dress" is "to dress oneself", but the object is merely understood rather than be overtly stated. The verbal idiom "dress up" means to dress in smart or formal clothes, or in some costume or fancy dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No object is needed:

> I shall dress before breakfast

but

> I shall dress up for dinner

means you will wear something formal or fancy.

There is a similar use of **up** with the verb **talk**:

> I shall talk about our plan

says the plan will be discussed, whereas

> I shall talk up our plan

says you will be using your talking skills to *promote* your plan.